# Ansible commands to pull file from remote server and prevent if exist already

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible, to host server(172.19.113.104) I want to copy files ( **ansibletest** & **MariaDB-client-5.1.67-122.el5.x86_64.rpm** ) from remote server(172.19.113.87), but it should not copy if file exist already.

I tried like below but throwing error:

```
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
   ip: 172.19.113.87
  tasks:
  - name: this is to pull
    local_action: shell 'ls /opt/ansibletest'
    register: result

  - name: ts2
    synchronize:  src={{ item }} dest=/opt/ mode=pull
    with_items:
    - "/opt/ansibletest"
    - "/opt/MariaDB-client-5.1.67-122.el5.x86_64.rpm"
    when: result.shell.exists == true









[root@rbtstaging ansible]# ansible-playbook fetch.yml

PLAY [webservers] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.19.113.87]

TASK [this is to pull] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.19.113.87]

TASK [ts2] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.19.113.87]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result.stat.exists == True' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.stat.exists == True): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/RND/sudhir/ansible/fetch.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: ts2\n    ^ here\n"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/RND/sudhir/ansible/fetch.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.19.113.87              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Note:** Files exist with permission

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend the fetch (fetch file from remote server - copy will send the file to the remove server) by a local "stat" operation, and check for existence of the local file.

```
local_action:
  module: stat
  path: /path/to/local/file
register: local_file
become: no

fetch:
  src: /path/to/remote/file
  dest: /path/to/local/file
  flat: yes
when: local_file.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: Its not working, the fetch module by default, if file already exist and data in it is same as present in same file of remote server then file wont get modify, if in remote server file changed then again I run playbook in that case it will replace file in my host server as its modified.............          My requirement is if it finds the file while copying then it should copy even file in remote server modified.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't parse that :-(

Comment: Also you switched to a shell command, where my example uses the state module - why?